# divide textfield number by 100 - swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, string, double

I am trying to divide a string by 100, although even after casting I am still getting errors.

```
 b?.text = String(Double(b!.text)!/100)
```

This is the error:

Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '(String?)'

I also tried the if let variation, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialized `Double` from `String?` and `b!.text` is `String?`. To fix this, you have to pass `String`. So you can your b’s `text` for example force-unwrap

```
b!.text!
```

Then you can use this:

```
 b?.text = String(Double(b!.text!)!/100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
let dbl_val = Double(b.text!)! / 100
b.text = String(dbl_val)
print(b.text!)
```

Output:

[image]